# When .VHD get updated?

Tags: hyper-v, vhd

I have a VM with a .vhd file. However, when I connect to the VM (by RDP) and make some changes (create a directory and add a small file with notepad) the .VHD file stays unchanged. The 'Date modified' of the .VHD stays at the start time of the VM.

1. How can we force an update of the VM while the VM is running?
2. Where are the temporary changes kept?

Hypervisor: Microsoft Hyper-V server 2008R2 (free download version)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you haven't taken any snapshots, the changes are in the VHD file you're looking at.  The file information will be updated when the file is closed, which is to say when you shut the VM down.

Comment: Which is standard behavior. YOu also do not look at a Hyper-V data item here. The datem odified is an item of the file system managed by standard windows. It does not get updated WHILE a file is open.